# Declare two String arrays, one extending the other in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to have the following declarations:

```
private static String[] BASE = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
private static String[] EXTENDED = BASE + new String[] { "d", "e", "f" };
```

The first line declares a string array with three (or more) string values.
The second line should declare a string array with all the string values from BASE and then add three (or more) string values.

Is this possible? If yes... how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, it's a simple one-liner:

Given the two arrays of your question like so:

```
private static String[] BASE = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
private static String[] EXTENSION = new String[] { "d", "e", "f" };
```

The solution would be:

```
String[] EXTENDED = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(BASE), Arrays.stream(EXTENSION))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: You may want to replace `Arrays.stream(EXTENDED)` with `Stream.of("d", "e", "f")`. Another alternative: `private static String[] EXTENDED = Stream.of(BASE, new String[] { "d", "e", "f" }).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new);` although not as short as `concat`.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct. Java 8 is still fairly new, and not a lot of people have explored the stream API to it's fullest.

Comment: @RobinJonsson: Well even knowing the stream API, I'd say it's not terribly simple. (The C# would be *somewhat* simpler: `BASE.Concat(EXTENDED).ToArray()`, but actually this doesn't show what's requested in the question - which is for `EXTENDED` to be `BASE` plus some other members... you might want to edit your answer to actually match the question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd say it's pretty simple. But that's my opinion after working with it in heavy business logic for about 6 months. Altough, I'm a fast learner ;) I've edited my answer to fit his example and question better. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @RobinJonsson: Thanks for the input. I'm actually stuck on Java 7 for this project so I can't use the Streams API. However, since I forgot to mention this I will acknowledge your answer with JonSkeet's comment.

Answer (score 4):

Not like that, no. You can use:

```
private static String[] EXTENDED = new String[BASE.length + 3];

static {
    System.arraycopy(BASE, 0, EXTENDED, 0, BASE.length);
    EXTENDED[BASE.length] = "d";
    EXTENDED[BASE.length + 1] = "e";
    EXTENDED[BASE.length + 2] = "f";
}
```

Or write a method to concatenate two arrays, then call it with:

```
private static String[] BASE = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
private static String[] EXTENDED =
    ArrayUtils.concat(BASE, new String[] { "d", "e", "f" });
```

I don't know of such a method in the JRE, but it wouldn't be hard to write - or use the streams API if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution in Apache Commons Lang library:
[ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(firstArray, secondArray);

Comment: Even with the improvements of Java 8 I still use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) frequently...it's my favorite general purpose library by far.  In this particular case the code you've posted is easier to read than the Java 8 one-line solution so I'd go with your solution if performance isn't a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Not relying on Java 8, here's another solution:

```
String[] BASE = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
String[] EXT = new String[] { "d", "e", "f" };

String[] CONCAT = Arrays.copyOf (BASE, BASE.length + EXT.length);
System.arraycopy(EXT, 0, CONCAT, BASE.length, EXT.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a `JoinedArray` class a while ago that could help. It's a bit of overkill if you dont want to do this very often but if you do this a lot in your code you may find it of use.

It does not actually join the arrays into a new one - it actually provides an `Iterable` that can then iterate across the joined arrays.

```
public class JoinedArray<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  final List<T[]> joined;

  @SafeVarargs
  public JoinedArray(T[]... arrays) {
    joined = Arrays.<T[]>asList(arrays);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new JoinedIterator<>(joined);
  }

  private class JoinedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    // The iterator across the arrays.
    Iterator<T[]> i;
    // The array I am working on.
    T[] a;
    // Where we are in it.
    int ai;
    // The next T to return.
    T next = null;

    private JoinedIterator(List<T[]> joined) {
      i = joined.iterator();
      a = i.hasNext() ? i.next() : null;
      ai = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      while (next == null && a != null) {
        // a goes to null at the end of i.
        if (a != null) {
          // End of a?
          if (ai >= a.length) {
            // Yes! Next i.
            if (i.hasNext()) {
              a = i.next();
            } else {
              // Finished.
              a = null;
            }
            ai = 0;
          }
          if (a != null) {
            if (ai < a.length) {
              next = a[ai++];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      T n = null;
      if (hasNext()) {
        // Give it to them.
        n = next;
        next = null;
      } else {
        // Not there!!
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
      return n;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JoinedArray<String> a = new JoinedArray<>(
            new String[]{
              "Zero",
              "One"
            },
            new String[]{},
            new String[]{
              "Two",
              "Three",
              "Four",
              "Five"
            },
            new String[]{
              "Six",
              "Seven",
              "Eight",
              "Nine"
            });
    for (String s : a) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create 2 Arrays
String[] first = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
String[] second = new String[]{"d","e","f"};

// Create a List
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Then add both arrays in the List
tempList.addAll(Arrays.asList(first));
tempList.addAll(Arrays.asList(second));

// Then convert the List into array
String[] finalStr =  tempList.toArray(new String[tempList.size()]);

// Thats it
```